# php curl abrupt behavior

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I am using php curl to fetch data from youtube. There are two curls. First curl executes successfully and retrieves the access token from youtube. 2nd curl uses this oauth token and retrieves the user info. But it shows unexpected behavior. sometimes it works absolutely fine but oftentimes it shows the error message `SSL Connection Timeout`.

If there is problem in code then why it works sometime
The code is

```
$url_userInfo =  'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default?access_token='.$_SESSION['yt_access_token'].'&v=2&alt=json';    
$curl = curl_init();
$header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/json, text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
$header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
$header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
$header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
$header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
$header[] = "Pragma: ";


curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.google.com');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url_userInfo);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY); //needed for SSL

$content = curl_exec($curl);
echo curl_error($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$res = json_decode($content);

print_r($res);
```

Comment: Doesn't YouTube have an API for this sort of stuff? https://developers.google.com/youtube/

Comment: Yes I am usin youtube API

Comment: Why don't you just use `file_get_contents()` and then `json_decode()` the result?

Comment: Its a cross domain request...  `file_get_contents()` won't work here

Comment: It should, this is server-side, not client-side.

Comment: @RanaMuhammadUsman `file_get_contents` might do the same thing, but it's very limited compared to cURL. You might be able to set some of the options using a context, but there really isn't any reason to use it over cURL. Have you tried to increase the timeout? Enable the cURL verbose option and look for more detailed errors.

Comment: Thanx @cryptic `file_get_contents` worked for me

Comment: @RanaMuhammadUsman, unless you are doing actions such as deleting or adding content, fetching is done using GET so file_get_contents() will work for it. Please accept answer below =o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$url_userInfo =  'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default?access_token='.$_SESSION['yt_access_token'].'&v=2&alt=json';
$content = file_get_contents($url_userInfo);
$res = json_decode($content);
print_r($res);
```

Comment: @Michael I'm looking at the API documentation, and the requests are handled via GET using token to retrieve JSON, so how would this not work?

Comment: @cryptic its working but there is another error `: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at...)` :(

Comment: @RanaMuhammadUsman, can you post the entire error message? It's being caused because you are outputting content somwhere before using session_start() or header(). I can help pinpoint the problem, but need the full error message. You can remove filepaths, but keep filenames please.

Comment: @cryptic `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\xampp\htdocs\uno\controller\y.php:16) in D:\xampp\htdocs\uno\controller\y.php on line 52` 

And the line 52 is 
`header("Location: ../closewindow.php?status=added");`

Comment: @RanaMuhammadUsman What is on line 16 of y.php and what is on line 52?

Comment: I have described in my above comment

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21939/discussion-between-cryptic-and-rana-muhammad-usman)

Answer (score 1):

There are chances that your connection is taking long time to stream data from you tube. So either
you can increase curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20); as per your need or you can re-curl 
it on failure.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some info in your headers. Specify the access token as the value of the Authorization: Bearer HTTP request header. Also remove `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT` and `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` options.
Following [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2#OAuth2_Calling_a_Google_API), the curl should be:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/".$vid."?alt=json&v=2&access_token=".$token);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: OAuth '.$token));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,  array('Content-length: 0'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);

$output = curl_exec($ch);

$http_response_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($ch);

$result = json_decode($output, true);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($result); echo "</pre>";
```